# How do I build wxWidget for portable CodeBlocks?

Tags: c++, makefile, mingw, wxwidgets, codeblocks

I'm new at this, so please bear with me.

Every tutorial tells me to go to the build\msw directory and start running the makefile command:

```
mingw32-make -f makefile.gcc BUILD=release SHARED=1 MONOLITHIC=1 UNICODE=1
```

The problem is that mingw32-make.exe is not in that directory. Do I just copy everything from my CodeBlocks\MinGW\bin folder to that directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do I just copy everything from my CodeBlocks\MinGW\bin folder to that
>   directory?

No! The right way to make the compiler tool-chain accessible from any location is to set the system's environment `PATH` variable.

Usually, you don't have to set this yourself; it's likely MinGW did this for you during installation. You can verify this by looking at your 'PATH' variable. Also, if you look in the root directory of where you installed MinGW you should find a batch script 'mingwvars.bat'. If you open a new 'cmd' terminal and run that batch script it will make the tool-chains accessible for that terminal session.